# JAVA Jacoco Incorrect line coverage

Tags: java, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I'm trying to use Jacoco to get code coverage for a Java 8 project.
For some reason, I see a low line coverage.

Gradle version: 4.8.1

Gradle.build

```
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "jacoco"

jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.5    "
    reportsDir = file("$buildDir/customJacocoReportDir")
}
jacocoTestReport {
    reports {
        xml.enabled false
        csv.enabled false
        html.destination file("${buildDir}/jacocoHtml")
    }
}
dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'org.easymock', name: 'easymock', version: '3.6'
    testCompile group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-easymock-release-full', version: '1.6.4'
}
```

When I use Java debugger I see during tests that there is a hit for the following line:

```
public class RangeStateStore {
    public void setRangeState(KeyValueStore<String, RangeStateObj>  kvStorage, RangeStateObj rangeStateObj) {
        kvStorage.put(rangeStateObj.key, rangeStateObj);
    }
```

But in the coverage:
[image: Jacoco coverage]

And when I run the coverage using IntelliJ coverage it gets a hit:
[image: IntelliJ coverage]

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as an idea:

I assume you're running jacoco as a java agent (runtime instrumentation).
In this case its possible that there is a class between bytecode instrumentation made by jacoco and bytecode modifications made by PowerMock.

As a result, its possible that the classes that are not covered are the classes that were loaded with PowerMock classloader.

See [this explanation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Code-coverage-with-JaCoCo)